# MySQL 8.0 returns 0 rows with LEFT JOIN insted of returning 1 row with 0 column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the SQL-query:

```
select user.*, count(call_out_end.id) as calls
from user
left join call_out_end on call_out_end.employer_id = user.id
where user.id = 949 and call_out_end.callstart >= '2018-12-09 00:00:00'
group by user.id
```

And this query returns exactly 0 rows (should return 1 row with column calls = 0).

[image]

If I do change the SQL-query to:

```
select user.*, count(call_out_end.id) as calls
from user
left join call_out_end on call_out_end.employer_id = user.id
where user.id = 949
group by user.id
```

MySQLWorkbench returns 1 row:

[image]

... but that's not what I want :)

I want to mention that there is **no records** which satisfy the condition: `call_out_end.callstart >= '....'`, so I expect to receive 0 calls.

Where am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters on the second table in a `left join` need to go in the `on` clause:

```
select u.*, count(coe.id) as calls
from user u left join
     call_out_end coe
     on coe.employer_id = user.id and
        coe.callstart >= '2018-12-09'
where u.id = 949 
group by u.id;
```

When the condition is in the `WHERE` clause, then the outer join is turned into an inner join.  Why?  Non-matched values of `callstart` have a `NULL` value and fail the comparison.

Notice that I also added table aliases to the query.  This makes it easier to write and to read.  I also removed the time component from the date constant.  It is unnecessary.

The `group by u.id` is okay, assuming that `u.id` is a primary key in `users` (which it no doubt is).

Comment: Damn... It was too easy! Thank you! Can you explain HOW the final result works when the condition is in WHERE clause instead of being moved to the ON part. Can't figure it out why it gives no results at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a LEFT JOIN to *optionally* match table secondary table `call_out_end`. If there is no match, you still want do display the records from primary table `user`.

The problem with your query is that your `WHERE` clause references a field from the secondary table (`callstart`). Hence, when the `LEFT JOIN` is not matched, `callstart`  comes up `NULL` in the `WHERE` clause, causing the corresponding record to be filtered out.

To solve the issue, you need to move the filter on that field from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` part of the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
select user.*, count(call_out_end.id) as calls
from user
left join call_out_end
    on call_out_end.employer_id = user.id
    and call_out_end.callstart >= '2018-12-09 00:00:00'
where user.id = 949
group by user.id
```

Conceptually this is the same query as the much uglier :

```
select user.*, count(call_out_end.id) as calls
from user
left join call_out_end
    on call_out_end.employer_id = user.id     
where 
    user.id = 949
    and (
        call_out_end.employer_id IS NULL
        or call_out_end.callstart >= '2018-12-09 00:00:00'
    )
group by user.id
```

Comment: >>Hence, when the LEFT JOIN is not matched, callstart comes up NULL in the WHERE clause.

I tried to add an OR call_out_end.callstart IS NULL, but it still gives me 0 rows.

Comment: Beware of operator prescendence when mixing OR and AND : `WHERE user.id = 949 and ( call_out_end.callstart IS NULL or call_out_end.callstart >= '2018-12-09 00:00:00' )` should work properly. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I know about operator prescendence, but this solution didn't work properly! I have tested it also and received 0 rows.

Comment: @AndrewShmig, this will work... Make sure you run the same query with the same dataset... But anyway, as explained in my answer, moving the condition to the LEFT JOIN is the recommended way to proceed...

Comment: Thanks! Will check it again.